# How to debug ASP.NET Core typescript files when they are placed in the same folder as the view (cshtml file) in ASP.NET Core 5+

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging

I am migrating an ASP.NET MVC app to ASP.NET Core 7. Moreover in my 'source' application all javascript and css files originates respectively from typescript and scss files.

Files for each `View` are organized in the same folder. E.g.:

```
.../Views/<controller_name1>
  Index.cshtml
  Index.ts
     Index.js
        Index.min.js
  Index.scss
     Index.css
        Index.min.css
```

and I'd like to have the same structure in the ASP.NET Core app even if, I know, static files should be places under `wwwroot`. So to overcome the point I used the smart solution [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42477887/752004).

The last issue I have is the Visual Studio debugging of the typescript/javascript files:

While in the legacy asp.net app it was enough that I set the breakpoints in VS2022 directly in the `.ts` file, with the ASP.NET Core app, this approach doesn't work.

Does anybody has a way to keep the logic I'd like to have?